# Error when creating a transition from bar chart to same bar chart but with different column

Tags: html, css, d3.js

I am trying to create a bar chart transition with the click button. However, it's showing an error in the function.

I want to transition from "frequency" to "average.winning.speed" by using the file from gist.github.

The code is little complicated because I have several resources from blockbuilder. Also, i have commented out the code from Image but i actually want to do is get the image in the background of the bar.

Could anybody resolve the issue and also explain the problem. Let me know if you need more details

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
  <div id="option">
    <input name="updateButton" 
           type="button" 
           value="Update" 
           onclick="updateData()" />
</div>
  
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

  
  <script>

// Mike Bostock "margin conventions"
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// D3 scales = just math
// x is a function that transforms from "domain" (data) into "range" (usual pixels)
// domain gets set after the data loads
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

// D3 Axis - renders a d3 scale in SVG
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10, "%");

// create an SVG element (appended to body)
// set size
// add a "g" element (think "group")
// annoying d3 gotcha - the 'svg' variable here is a 'g' element
// the final line sets the transform on <g>, not on <svg>



    //(body = d3.select("body"); 
   
    //show_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/eb/Tour_de_France_logo.svg")

    
//function show_image(source) { 
//var img = body.append("img").attr("src", source).style("opacity", 0);   //img.transition().duration(5000).ease(d3.easeLinear).style("opacity", 1)
//} )
    


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .append("text") // just for the title (ticks are automatic)
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)") // rotate the text!
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

// d3.tsv is a wrapper around XMLHTTPRequest, returns array of arrays (?) for a TSV file
// type function transforms strings to numbers, dates, etc.
d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vaibhavjaitly/1418c9beb1c71f6acffdaf21669e1956/raw/0efab262a7dd56c3f11a1fea41cb3de8d82444d0/data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  replay(data);
});

function type(d) {
  // + coerces to a Number from a String (or anything)
  d.Frequency = +d.Frequency;
  return d;
}

function replay(data) {
  var slices = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    slices.push(data.slice(0, i+1));
  }
  slices.forEach(function(slice, index){
    setTimeout(function(){
      draw(slice);
    }, index * 300);
  });
}

function draw(data) {
  // measure the domain (for x, unique letters) (for y [0,maxFrequency])
  // now the scales are finished and usable
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Frequency; })]);

  // another g element, this time to move the origin to the bottom of the svg element
  // someSelection.call(thing) is roughly equivalent to thing(someSelection[i])
  //   for everything in the selection\
  // the end result is g populated with text and lines!
  svg.select(".x.axis").transition().duration(300).call(xAxis);

  // same for yAxis but with more transform and a title
  svg.select(".y.axis").transition().duration(300).call(yAxis)

  // THIS IS THE ACTUAL WORK!
  var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data, function(d) { return d.Letter; }) // (data) is an array/iterable thing, second argument is an ID generator function

  bars.exit()
    .transition()
      .duration(300)
    .attr("y", y(0))
    .attr("height", height - y(0))
    .style('fill-opacity', 0.00001024)
    .remove();

  // data that needs DOM = enter() (a set/selection, not an event!)
  bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("y", y(0))
    .attr("height", height - y(0));

  // the "UPDATE" set:
  bars.transition().duration(300).attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Letter); }) // (d) is one item from the data array, x is the scale object from above
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand()) // constant, so no callback function(d) here
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Frequency); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.Frequency); }); // flip the height, because y's domain is bottom up, but SVG renders top down

}
    
    // ** Update data section (Called from the onclick)
function updateData() {

    d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vaibhavjaitly/1418c9beb1c71f6acffdaf21669e1956/raw/0efab262a7dd56c3f11a1fea41cb3de8d82444d0/data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  replay(data);
});

function type(d) {
  // + coerces to a Number from a String (or anything)
  d.['Average.Winning.Speed'] = +d.['Average.Winning.Speed'];
  return d;
}

function replay(data) {
  var slices = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i) {
    slices.push(data.slice(0, i+1));
  }
  slices.forEach(function(slice, index){
    setTimeout(function(){
      draw(slice);
    }, index * 300);
  });
}

function draw(data) {
  // measure the domain (for x, unique letters) (for y [0,maxFrequency])
  // now the scales are finished and usable
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.['Average.Winning.Speed']; })]);

  // another g element, this time to move the origin to the bottom of the svg element
  // someSelection.call(thing) is roughly equivalent to thing(someSelection[i])
  //   for everything in the selection\
  // the end result is g populated with text and lines!
  svg.select(".x.axis").transition().duration(300).call(xAxis);

  // same for yAxis but with more transform and a title
  svg.select(".y.axis").transition().duration(300).call(yAxis)

  // THIS IS THE ACTUAL WORK!
  var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data, function(d) { return d.Letter; }) // (data) is an array/iterable thing, second argument is an ID generator function

  bars.exit()
    .transition()
      .duration(300)
    .attr("y", y(0))
    .attr("height", height - y(0))
    .style('fill-opacity', 0.00001024)
    .remove();

  // data that needs DOM = enter() (a set/selection, not an event!)
  bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("y", y(0))
    .attr("height", height - y(0));

  // the "UPDATE" set:
  bars.transition().duration(300).attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Letter); }) // (d) is one item from the data array, x is the scale object from above
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand()) // constant, so no callback function(d) here
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.['Average.Winning.Speed']); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.['Average.Winning.Speed']); }); // flip the height, because y's domain is bottom up, but SVG renders top down

}}
    
   

</script>
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please include the error you're receiving?

Comment: Hey. I am receiving the error on 184 line. I am trying to build it through block builder. Error: Cannot read property of "length" of undefined